# Problem texturing a complex model like the interlaced leaves of a palm tree

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have several models of palm trees that I have to texture. As you can see on the picture, selecting the polygons is problematic. Most of the leaves are interlaced with other leaves and large parts of the leaves are hidden by other leaves. It's very hard to view whole face of a leaf and also to select the vertices properly.

I have seen different tutorials for making a palm tree and the artists created the leaves and applied the texture before joining the leaves altogether at the top. That does not work in a case where you have to texture an imported model.

Does anyone have techniques to work with the polygons (texturing and other modifications) of complex models where there are hidden parts like in the case of a palm tree?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this neat selection trick : just click on the ending vertex of a leaf, and do "CTRL +" repeatedly to increment your selection. "CTRL -" to deselect.

Another trick that you can also try is to hover over a leaf, and hit L on the keyboard. This will select the actual object as a whole (provided it is a separate mesh). You can hide it by pressing H, and reactivate it with ALT+H.

Hope it helped, and welcome aboard !

Comment: and shift H if you want to select everything but the selected mesh